# Issue with SimpleDateFormat parsing date generated by strftime

Tags: java, python, timestamp, simpledateformat, strftime

I have a timestamp string
`2013-03-01T11:22:18.01Z` generated by `strftime("%Y:%m:%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`, which is in Python.

Now I'm trying to use Java's `SimpleDateFormat` to parse this timestamp. Lot's of sample code that I found seem to do this:

```
String DATE_FORMAT = "YYYY-MM-DD'T'hh:mm:ss.ssZ"
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT)
sdf.setLenient(false)
sdf.parse(timestamp) <---- throws ParseException here
```

However, I get an error dialog that says
`Unparseable date: "2013-03-01T11:22:18.01Z"`

I've been tweaking `DATE_FORMAT` here and there, trying all sorts of things but I've been stuck on the same roadblock for quite a while now. Looks like I'll need to borrow the power of the stackoverflow community on this.

Comment: Read the javadoc SimpleDateFormat [patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: That should be `yyyy`, not `YYYY`, and `dd`, not `DD`. Also `HH` instead of `hh`, etc -- like mentioned, go see the javadoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the `yyyy` vs `YYYY` and `dd` versus `DD`, the `Z` is also causing a problem. Your `SimpleDateFormat` with a pattern like

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ssZ
 |   |  |  | |  |  |  | |
 |   |  |  | |  |  |  | -----timezone (RFC 822 time zone, ex: -0800)
 |   |  |  | |  |  |  -------seconds again (maybe you wanted SS for milliseconds)
 |   |  |  | |  |  ----------seconds (0-59)
 |   |  |  | |  -------------minutes (0-59)
 |   |  |  | ----------------hours (0-23)
 |   |  |  ------------------the character T
 |   |  ---------------------day in month 
 |   ------------------------month in year
 ----------------------------year
```

But the String you pass, `"2013-03-01T11:22:18.01Z"`, simply has a Z at the end, not a timezone.

If you are actually expecting a `Z` at the end, then you need to quote it in the format string:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ss'Z'
```

just like you did for `T`. From the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation.

Comment: The `ss` after the dot should really be `SS` (for microseconds)

Comment: @fge It really should.

Answer (score 0):

1) correct pattern for 2013-03-01T11:22:18.01 is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"` (if .01 is millis)

2) Z timezone in 2013-03-01T11:22:18.01Z cannot be parsed by SimpleDateFormat 'Z' which  accepts only -0800 format (RFC 822). Even if you change it to 'z' (General time zone) it still wont parse Z, it should  be GMT

see SimmpleDateFormat API.

3) 2013-03-01T11:22:18.01Z looks like very much XSD dateTime format http://www.schemacentral.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_dateTime.html and can be parse with  DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime from java.xml.bind package (Java standard library)